# register widget class not written in theme

Tags: widgets

I have a widget located at `/child-theme/includes/custom-widget.php`.

How do I call `register_widget` and reference that widget?

I've tried something like the following inside `functions.php`:

```
function SER_register_widgets() { 
  register_widget( 'includes/custom-widget.php' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'SER_register_widgets' );
```

but this does not work.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include that file in your functions.php file like

`require_once('includes/custom-widgets.php');`

then you can call `add_action()` hook, in your case

`add_action('widgets_init', 'SER_register_widgets'); .`

the idea is to make that function ( ser_register_widgets ) visible in current php file ( functions.php file in this case )

Answer (score 0):

OK, that's not how PHP works... ;)

[`register_widget`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) function gets exactly one param - widget class... You can't pass a file path as a class name... Of course you have to make sure, that such class exists (so you have to include file with that class).

```
include_once( 'includes/custom-widget.php' );

function SER_register_widgets() { 
  register_widget( 'My_Custom_Widget_Class' );  // <-- change to real class
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'SER_register_widgets' );
```